# 'quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url' property must be configured. only when running the quarkus app on docker

Tags: java, docker, devops, keycloak, quarkus

**TOPIC**

I'm running a quarkus application and I want to connect it with a keycloak server deployed on another host.

the keycloak server is working with other services means no problems in there.

The keycloak server is exposing this hostname: `flitch.hostname.com`. So the url to connect to it is
`QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_SERVER_URL=http://flitch.hostame.com/realms/realmname`

***When running the quarkus project locally everything works fine, I can manage users, auth, tokens...***.

**PROBLEM**

But the when creating an image and running it on a the docker container it throws an error: `'quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url' property must be configured`

**DEBUGGING**

- `QUARKUS_OIDC_ENABLED=false` ( disabled the OIDC ) then running the project in the container, results to server is running well, in the mean time I've sent a curl request from the container bash to the `QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_SERVER_URL` it returns a success reponse with the appropriate json response. also tried `printenv` inside the container and all env vars exists and are set correctly.
- Changed the correct url to any other url e.g.`http://flitch.hostame.com/auth/realms/realmname/` in the container it logs an error message saying the server url is unreachable or denied, alongside the old error of `'quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url' property must be configured`

**FILES**

`application.properties`

```
# OIDC Configuration
    quarkus.keycloak.devservices.realm-path=${QUARKUS_KEYCLOAK_DEVSERVICES_REALM_PATH}
quarkus.oidc.client-id=${QUARKUS_OIDC_CLIENT_ID}
quarkus.oidc.credentials.jwt.signature-algorithm=${QUARKUS_OIDC_CREDENTIALS_JWT_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM}
quarkus.oidc.enabled=${QUARKUS_OIDC_ENABLED}
quarkus.oidc.auth-role-mapper.authentication.verify-access-token=${QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_ROLE_MAPPER_AUTHENTICATION_VERIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN}
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=${QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_SERVER_URL}
%prod.quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=${QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_SERVER_URL}
%dev.quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=${QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_SERVER_URL}
%test.quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=${QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_SERVER_URL}
quarkus.oidc.auth-role-mapper.authentication.cookie-force-secure=${QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_ROLE_MAPPER_AUTHENTICATION_COOKIE_FORCE_SECURE}
```

`.env`

```
QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_SERVER_URL=http://flitch.hostame.com/realms/realmname
_DEV_QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_SERVER_URL=http://flitch.hostame.com/realms/realmname
_TEST_QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_SERVER_URL=http://flitch.hostame.com/realms/realmname
_PROD_QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_SERVER_URL=http://flitch.hostame.com/realms/realmname
QUARKUS_OIDC_CLIENT_ID=account
QUARKUS_OIDC_CREDENTIALS_JWT_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM=****
QUARKUS_OIDC_ENABLED=true
QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_ROLE_MAPPER_AUTHENTICATION_VERIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN=true
QUARKUS_LIVE_RELOAD_INSTRUMENTATION=true
JAVAX_VALIDATION_ENABLE=true
QUARKUS_CONFIG_PATH=.env
QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_ROLE_MAPPER_AUTHENTICATION_COOKIE_FORCE_SECURE=false
QUARKUS_KEYCLOAK_DEVSERVICES_REALM_PATH=keycloak.json
QUARKUS_KEYCLOAK_REALM=realmname
QUARKUS_KEYCLOAK_DEVSERVICES_SHOW_LOGS=true
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  quarkus:
    image: quarkus/quarkus-project
    container_name: quarkus_project_container
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    build:
      context: $PWD
      dockerfile: ./src/main/docker/Dockerfile.jvm
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - 5005:5005
      - 8080:8080
```

And docker file is the default one generated by quarkus:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-17:1.14

ENV LANGUAGE='en_US:en'

# We make four distinct layers so if there are application changes the library layers can be re-used
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/lib/ /deployments/lib/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/*.jar /deployments/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/app/ /deployments/app/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/quarkus/ /deployments/quarkus/

EXPOSE 8080
USER 185
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Ddebug -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
ENV JAVA_DEBUG="true"
ENV JAVA_APP_JAR="/deployments/quarkus-run.jar"
```

Comment: I've tried this with https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/security-keycloak-authorization-quickstart, copied your configurations, and it worked as expected. Can you provide a reproducer?